# Failed to execute 'setSelectionRange' on 'HTMLInputElement'

Tags: google-chrome, webkit, numbers

I have the following error an simle "number" input field in Chrome (ver. 33 =>) and other webkit browsers

```
<input type="number" name="number">
```

> Failed to execute 'setSelectionRange' on 'HTMLInputElement': The input
>   element's type ('number') does not support selection.

I tested in FF & IE (10=>) and working well

I found the following issue in chromium project:
https://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=346270

any idea?

thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, this is an webkit bug, try this solution:

[Jsfiddle demo](http://fiddle.jshell.net/DqY8c/show/)

Code:

```html
    <div class="container">
        <form role="form">
          <div class="form-group">
            <label for="tel">tel</label>
              <input type="tel" class="form-control" id="tel" placeholder="tel"/>
          </div>
        </form>
    </div>

    <script>
    $("#tel").mask("(99) 999-9999");

    $("#tel").on("blur", function() {
        var last = $(this).val().substr( $(this).val().indexOf("-") + 1 );

        if( last.length == 3 ) {
            var move = $(this).val().substr( $(this).val().indexOf("-") - 1, 1 );
            var lastfour = move + last;
            var first = $(this).val().substr( 0, 9 );

            $(this).val( first + '-' + lastfour );
        }
    });
    </script>
```

Comment: more than a bug, it is a purposed defeaturing to match a spec :(